# iOS's UIWebView loading URL with apostrophe

Tags: html, ios, uiwebview, apostrophe

I have an app that uses `UIWebView` to load a local html file. the file is called "newton's second law.html" for example but because of that apostrophe, the file won't load. I have tried taking out the apostrophe with then works. So my question is how can I load a local URL with the apostrophe? Is there supposed to be an escape key that I can use? 
I load the file with this line: `filePath` is the absolute path to the file

```
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath]]];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to load the file using:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/path/to/your/file/newton\'s.html"];
```

Comment: Would it be newton\\'s.html? And yes I just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: No it would be just newton\'s second law.html

Answer (score 0):

Let's try:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[filePath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```